# stand up independent version of Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm an entry level web designer and my boss just asked me to research if it was possible to "stand up and independent version of Magento 2". I'm very new to CMS and have no clue where to start this process, if it's at all possible. Does someone know what he is asking for and if it's doable? Any/all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 has two options.

- Magento 2 Commerce Edition: Includes Support and extra feautures, costs $22,000+ annually
- Magento 2 Open Source Edition: Free open source code, requires some programming knowledge, fully customizable

I'm guessing your boss is talking about setting up a community edition of Magento. You would be able to make any changes to the code that you'd like.
You're boss may also be asking if its like Linux where you can take the code and create your own version that can then be resold. In which case, no there is not really anyone doing that, that I know of.
Ask your boss to explain what he's saying. Let me know if this helps!